# How to Loading Static Files in Django Template?

Tags: python, django

**Problem Description:**
I'm trying to set up a directory structure in my Django project where the `static` folder is inside the `user` folder, which is in turn inside the `templates` folder. My intention is to have static files located close to the template files. However, I'm having difficulties getting Django to properly serve static files from this directory structure.

**Directory Structure:**

```
project/
├── templates/
│   └── user/
│       ├── index.html
│       └── static/
│           └── css/
│               └── main.css
└── ...
```

**Additional Details:**

- I've configured `STATIC_URL` in `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'/static/')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/static")
```

- In my `index.html` file, I'm using the  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">` tag to reference static files.

**Issue Faced:**
Despite adjusting the settings, I'm unable to make Django serve static files properly from this specific directory structure. I've tried different configurations, such as changing `STATIC_URL`, but I still haven't succeeded. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us how `BASE_DIR` is set in settings.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

1. **Updating `STATICFILES_DIRS`:** In the `settings.py` file, the user had initially configured `STATICFILES_DIRS` with the path `'C:/user/templates/user/static'`. However, this path structure was incorrect.
2. **Removing Leading Slash:** The user removed the leading slash before `'user/templates/user/static'` in the `os.path.join` call to establish a proper path.

   ```py
   STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'user/templates/user/static')]
   ```
3. **Using Forward Slashes:** The user ensured the use of forward slashes `/` in the directory path, even on Windows systems, as Python and Django internally handle path conversions.
4. **Restarting Server:** After applying these changes, the user restarted the Django development server to enact the configuration.

---